# Eigenfunctions of Laplacian, what's wrong in the following argument?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in the following argument?? 
Consider a closed riemannian manifold $M$. Let $f$ be an eigenfunction
which corresponds to the first nonzero eigenvalue of Laplacian on $M$.
We set $f_0:=\max\{f,0\}$ and $f_1:=\max\{-f,0\}$. Then we have $f=f_0-f_1$.
Since $f$ is orthogonal to constant functions on $M$, $f_0$ and $f_1$
are non-trivial. Also these two functions are Lipschitz, so they are
in the Sobolev space $H^1(M)$. It is known that the zero set has finite
codimension one Hausodorff measure so the zero set is negligible.
Computing the Rayleigh quotient we get
\begin{align*}
R(f):=\frac{\int_M |\nabla f|^2}{\int_M f^2}=\frac{\int_M |\nabla f_0|^2 +\int_M   |\nabla f_1|^2}{\int_M f_0^2 +\int_M f_1^2 },
\end{align*}which implies one of $R(f_0)$ and $R(f_1)$ is at most the first
nontrivial eigenvalue $\lambda_1(M)$. Let's say $R(f_0)\leq \lambda_1(M)$.
It is known from regularity theory of elliptic PDE theory that $f_0$ is
an eigenfunction corresponding to $\lambda_1(M)$ but this is a contradiction
since $f_0$ is not orthogonal to constant function.

Comment: Why don't you work out this argument in the special case $M=S^1$ and $f(\theta)=\cos\theta$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. You'll see what is the problem with your argument.

Comment: $R(f)$ ca be  *any* nonnegative number. The  condition t $R(f)\leq \lambda_1(M)$  does not imply that $f$ is an eigenvalue.  See this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem

Comment: Liviu, $R(f)\leq \lambda_1(M)$ implies $R(f)=\lambda_1(M)$ for non constant function $f$. So $f$ becomes an eigenfunction.

Comment: Not true.  Take the case $f(\theta)=1+\sin\theta$. Then $f'(\theta)=\cos\theta$, $\Vert f\Vert^2=\int_0^{2\pi} (1+\sin^2\theta) d\theta= 3\pi$, $\Vert f'\Vert^2=\pi$, $R(f)=\frac{1}{3}<1=\lambda_1(S^1)$.

Comment: $\lambda_1(M)=\inf R(f)$, where $f$ is taken over all no constant function in $H^1(M)$, so it is true.

Comment: Oh now I see. I have to add the condition $f$ is orthogonal to constant functions among elements in $H^1(M)$. Thanks, Liviu is right.